# Minimum length regular expression for $\{ w| w\in\{0,1\}^* $ and for every x that is a prefix of w, $|\#1(x)-\#0(x)| \leq2\}$

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

[image]

$L(M) = $ $\{ w| w\in\{0,1\}^* $ and for every x that is a prefix of w, $|\#1(x)-\#0(x)| \leq2\}$

I tried to use some online convertors and only found this regular expression:
((a+(ϵ+a(ab)*b+b(ba)*a)(a(ab)*b+b(ba)*a)*a)(ab)*+b(ba)*)a+a+a(ab)*(ϵ+ab)+(ϵ+a(ab)*b+b(ba)*a)(a(ab)*b+b(ba)*a)*(a+a(ab)*(ϵ+ab+b)+b+b(ba)*(ϵ+ba+a)+ϵ)+((b+(ϵ+a(ab)*b+b(ba)*a)(a(ab)*b+b(ba)*a)*b)(ba)*+a(ab)*)b+b+b(ba)*(ϵ+ba)+ϵ

Can someone help me find a shorter one.

Thanks!

Comment: Your alphabet is $\{0,1\}$, not $\{a,b\}$. Furthermore, you can keep the picture, but please retype the exercise, so that anyone wanting to answer your question can copy-paste easily.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. When an exercise looks too complicated, try first a simpler version.
In this particular instance, first consider the language
$$
L_1 = \bigl\{ w \in \{0,1\}^* \mid \text{and for every prefix $p$ of $w$, $\big||p|_1 - |p|_0\big| \leqslant 1$}\bigr\}
$$